# how enable CSS after installing Xampp

Tags: drupal

when i installed new version of xampp and then tranfered my all database and data files. but after completion i can't display css of site. what is actual problem?
 I have seen all setting of setting.php , Clear cache And all but all are vein. help me?

Answer (score 0):

If CSS is not applied to your document, check your document to see if CSS is properly called. It's not problem of XAMPP or Browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure your rewrite mod enable in apache .